# PDO instance is not created in database class

Tags: php, pdo

I am implementing a PDO php class.

Inside my database class I have set the server and database correctly in the variable `$pdo`.

When creating a new PDO instance `($this->dbh = new PDO(...))` this is not created as I have implemented `var_dump($this->dbh)` and from the console I receive an empty object `(object(PDO)#3 (0) { } )`.

This is the code of db.php.

```
class Database {

private $server = server;
private $username = username;
private $password = password;
private $db = db;
private $dbh;
private $error;  

private $stmt;

public function get_dbh(){
    return $this->dbh;

}


public function Database()
{
    $pdo = "mysql:host=" . $this->server . ";db=" . $this->db;
    //var_dump($pdo);
    // Set options
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );
    // Create new PDO instanace
    try {
        $this->dbh = new PDO($pdo, $this->username, $this->password, $options);
        var_dump($this->dbh);
    } // Catch the exception
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: For example  //var_dump($pdo) gives me "mysql:host=localhost;db=dbname" and from var_dump($this->dbh); I am expecting to receive the details of the pdo object with the username and password details of my database

Comment: Since I receive object(PDO)#3 (0) { } I assume the instance is not created.

Comment: When something is not created it is NULL

Comment: Ok so is it correct to receive object(PDO)#3 (0) { } ? If it is, the problem is in another file.

Comment: I don't see any problem. Make a query to database and confirm that your code works.

Comment: The problem is in the query. private function getData($query){
        
        $dbo = new Database();
     //var_dump($dbo);
//        $rname=$dbo->get_dbh();
       //var_dump($rname);
       
       $select_stmt = $dbo->get_dbh()->prepare($query);
       $select_stmt->$execute($query);
       $row = $select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        
       return $row;
        
   }

Comment: Using eponymous method name as a constructor is deprecated. Also, this class at whole is rather wrong. My advise is to create a vanilla PDO instance and use it in your code